# Compiling C/C++ Library for Raspberry Pi Toolchain

Tags: cross-compiling, libraries, raspberry-pi, toolchain

I have been working on setting up a toolchain for Raspberry Pi development. I have had no problem setting up [the official Raspberry Pi cross-compiler](http://github.com/raspberrypi/tools), but now I am beginning to require some external libraries, like OpenSSL, as well as the OpenMAX libraries that were recently released.

What is the simplest way to integrate C/C++ libraries into the cross-compiler?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I have found a way to use 3rd party libraries with the cross compilers, however it doesn't seem optimal. Basically, I just installed the libraries I required onto my Raspberry Pi (running Arch Linux)

```
pi:# pacman -S libssl-dev
```

then used

```
pi:# tar -zcvf include.tar.gz /usr/include
pi:# tar -zcvf lib.tar.gz /usr/lib
```

to compress the include and lib directories on my Pi.

Next, I copied them over to my local machine (i686 running Debian squeeze) running the cross compiler via `sftp`:

```
debian:$ sftp root@<pi_ip_address>:/usr/include.tar.gz
debian:$ sftp root@<pi_ip_address>:/usr/lib.tar.gz
```

I backed up the cross compiler's `include` and `lib` directories using the command (as root, since my cross directory is in `/opt`)

```
debian:# tar -zcvf OLDinclude.tar.gz ./include
debian:# tar -zcvf OLDlib.tar.gz ./lib
```

and proceded to extract the archives from the Pi to the cross compiler's `sysroot/usr/` directory.

Finally, to test if it worked, I compiled a program I using the library using both `<cross>-gcc` and `<cross>-g++` . . . and it worked! Now, I might write a bash script to take care of most of these steps for me. If anybody has any tips on how to streamline this process, please advise.

---

**Note:** For other Linux newcomers like me, `'$'` represents a normal user shell, while `'#'` represents a superuser (i.e. root) shell. Normal users can upgrade to a super user using the `su` command.

Comment: wouldn't that override host system libs?